# Count visible elements from any similar ID

Tags: jquery, append

How can I append text to elements containing a certain word in the ID, as long as they contain a visible element? I can get this to work for one unique ID, but not for all IDs containing the match (the one visible element). I've a feeling my use of "this" is incorrect.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wukbj/1/ [EDIT now with jQuery enabled!!!]

```
$(function() {
if ($("[id^=relatedelements] > li:visible").length == 1) {
    $(this).append("match found...")};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `id*=value` which means `id` **contains** the string `value`

```
$(function() {
    $("ul[id*=relatedelements] > li:visible").each(function(){
        $(this).append('match found...');
    })
});
```

for non visible element:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul[id*=relatedelements] > li:hidden").each(function(){
        $(this).append('match found...');
    })
});
```

You can also count the number of `hidden` element and append it to the `ul`

```
$(function() {
    $("ul[id*=relatedelements]").each(function(){
        $(this).append($(this).find('li:hidden').length 
          + ' items are invisible...');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great, if I wanted it the other way around how can I amend `$(this).find('li:visible').append('match found...');` to find INVISIBLE elements, and make the append there?

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it in a Fiddle but the message is not being added to the list which contains invisible elements, could you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/Wukbj/2/

Comment: of course because it is invisible, you should inspect the dom in order to see it...

Comment: where do you want the text. in the <li> or next to the <ul>?

Comment: At the end of the <ul>, as one occurrence.

Comment: ok see my update to the question, this should solve your issue. let me know

Comment: Almost there - if items are found I don't want any message to display, and I don't want the number to display. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wukbj/3/ thank you so much.

Comment: so what do you want? It is hard to understand... can you explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: if you want nothing to be displayed, what is the goal of the javascript code?

Comment: I am sorry, I will explain. It is a dynamic system where you can check and uncheck boxes to show and hide elements. If a DIV like `<div id="relatedelements">` or `<div id="relatedelements123">` contains all invisible elements, I want to display a message like "no matches found". If it contains block elements, display no message. Sorry for not giving more detail.

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much John. I'm really grateful for your help, I've been stuck on this problem for hours!!